# Error : encoded URI return an error on a nextjs app deployed with firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, uri, encodeuricomponent

I have an nextjs app deployed on firebase. Each product that has a space encoded with %20 returns an error : An unexpected error occurred.
It worked well on localhost but not anymore when I deploy.
Do you know why?

api.js

```
export async function fetchAPI(path) {
  const requestUrl = getStrapiURL(path);
  const response = await fetch(requestUrl);
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
}

export async function getProduct(name) {
  const products = await fetchAPI(`/books?name=${name}`);
  return products?.[0];
}
```

[name.js]

```
const paths = products.map(
    (product) => `/books/${encodeURIComponent(product.name)}`
  );
  return { paths, fallback: false };
}
```

Comment: At what point exactly does the error happen? Could you add the error and error stack?

Comment: I find away by removing encodeURIComponent from [name].js and use the method in the <Link> from the page that lead to this one. Sorry it's kind of a tricky explanation. But I didn't find the way to replace %20 by - to have a cleaner URL actually